# React and Redux toolkit : loose the state when I want to use filter action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to create a button to filter the data according to the entered value.

I have created a button in a header component and my project list in a main component.

My problem is that when I dispatch my 'projectFilter' action from my button in the header, it filters the data, but I lose the initial state.

There is my project slicer

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

let lastId = 2;

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "projects",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    projectAdded: (state, action) => {
      state.push({
        id: ++lastId,
        name: action.payload.name,
        gender: action.payload.gender,
      });
    },
    projectFilter: (state, action) => {
      return state.filter((project) => project.id === action.payload.id);
    },
  },
});

export const { projectAdded, projectFilter } = slice.actions;
export default slice.reducer;
```

There is my two button for Adding a project and filtering a project

```
function Header() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="header">
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          dispatch(
            projectAdded({ name: "project name", gender: "project gender" })
          )
        }
      >
        Add project
      </button>
      <input type="number" onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(projectFilter({ id: Number(value) }))}>
        Filter
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

And finally there is my list of project which I render in my page

```
function Main() {
  const projects = useSelector((state) => state.projects);
  return (
    <div className="main">
      {projects.map((project) => (
        <p key={project.id}>
          {project.id} {project.name} {project.gender}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

Could you please help me to filter data without loosing the all state ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Filtering is something that you want to do with a selector rather than with an action.  You want the state to still contain every item, but you select from it only the ones that match your condition.  Right now you are changing your state to only include the matching items so all the others will be lost.

Comment: It can be done purely via a selector where the selector is based on the filter id.  Or it can be a combination of an action and a selector where the action just stores the filter id somewhere in your state.  The selector selects both the filter id and the array of items from the state.  It then returns a filtered array containing just the matches.  Since you have your code in two separate components you probably want the action + selector approach.  If using just a selector, store the filter id in the local state of a shared parent of Header and Main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Actions vs. Selectors

When you dispatch an action you are permanently changing the state.  You do not want to replace `state.projects` with only the items matching the current filter.  You want to keep all of your items in the state and *select* just the ones that match.  This something that you do with the selector function inside of `useSelector` in `Main`.

### Storing the Current Filter

Your selector function needs to know the filter id in order to filter matches.  You can store that id in the component via `useState` or you can store the filter id as a property in your redux store (either in the projects slice or in another slice).

If you were editing the filter and displaying the filtered results from the same component, I would recommend the `useState` approach.  With two separate components you can still do it, but the state would have to be stored in a shared parent and passed down via props.  I don't know the relationship between your `Main` and `Header` components, so for this case I recommend storing the current filter in redux.  You will `dispatch` an action to set the current filter.  Basically that action just updates the stored filter id.  The job of applying the filter still goes to to the selector.

### lastId

Reducers should not rely on an external state.  You don't want `lastId` to be just some variable in the file.  You need to get an id from the state itself.  You could look for the maximum id among the current projects, or you could store `lastId` as a property in the state.

### Code

Slice

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState: {
    projects: [],
    lastId: 2, // why not 0 or 1?
    filter: null, // is just the id right now, but could be a complex object
}

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "projects",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    projectAdded: (state, action) => {
      state.projects.push({
        id: ++state.lastId,
        name: action.payload.name,
        gender: action.payload.gender,
      });
    },
    projectFilter: (state, action) => {
      state.filter = action.payload.id;
    },
  },
});

export const { projectAdded, projectFilter } = slice.actions;
export default slice.reducer;
```

No changes to Header

Main

```
function Main() {
  const projects = useSelector(
      // could move this function to another file
      // this could be written more concisely, but I'm trying to be clear instead
      (state) => {
          const all = state.projects.projects;
          const filterId = state.projects.filter;
          if ( filterId === null ) {
              return all;
          }
          else {
            return all.filter( project => project.id === filterId );
          }
  });
  return (
    <div className="main">
      {projects.map((project) => (
        <p key={project.id}>
          {project.id} {project.name} {project.gender}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```